# Changing translation on GitHub page homepage with mkdocs-static-i18n results in a 404

Tags: internationalization, github-pages, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

So I have built a website using GitHub Pages and mkdocs. I'm using mkdocs-static-i18n to deploy a translation (in French). Everything works great *except* on the main page (the one built from index.md). If I try to change the language on that page, I get a 404. Any idea what the issue might be? I'm using the folder version of static-i18n. Here's the relevant code with site name obscured:

```
- i18n:
      docs_structure: folder
      default_language: en
      languages:
        - locale: en
          default: true
          name: English
          build: true
          site_name: My website
          site_description: My description
        - locale: fr
          name: Français
          build: true
          site_name: French name
          site_description: French description
          nav_translations:
            My stuff
extra:
  alternate:
    # Switch to English
    - name: English
      link: /en/
      lang: en

    # Switch to French
    - name: Français
      link: /fr/
      lang: fr
```

I tried changing the name of index.md to homepage to avoid this issue, but I get the same problem and the base link doesn't redirect properly to my homepage.

**Edit:** I have noticed clicking on the translation shortens my URL. For instance, if the homepage is something.github.io/some-page, it turns into something.github.io/fr instead of something.github.io/some-page/fr. I assume this is the problem.

Comment: I assume this is on a project page, not a user or organization page, right? (See [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites) for the distinction). I don't know static-i18n, but I assume there's some setting to configure the base URL. Looking at [their own configuration](https://github.com/ultrabug/mkdocs-static-i18n/blob/main/mkdocs.yml), maybe the `site_url` config setting? You don't show that part of your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was related to the `alternate` portion of the config. In case this is helpful to anyone, here's what I changed to make it work:

```
extra:
  alternate:
    # Switch to English
    - name: English
      link: ""
      lang: en

    # Switch to French
    - name: Français
      link: fr
      lang: fr
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).